# java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection when starting Tomcat v9.0.2.0 using JVM v1.8.0_162

Tags: java, tomcat, ioexception

I have deployed a working application onto a 64 Bit Windows 7 Professional test VM at a client site.  The tomcat instance is unable to start.

When Tomcat tries to establish its Connectors, they all fail with the above exception.  The exception highlights are:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifeCycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
Caused by: java.net.ConnectionException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I am able to ping localhost, 127.0.0.1 and loopback without issue.

The default listening port is 8098.  I have tried changing it to ports in the 100s and also ports in the 10000s.

I have tried removing and adding Connectors.  They all fail with the same error.

I have tried disabling the IPv6 protocol on the only adapter in the VM.

I have tried adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable.

I have tried lots of low hanging fruit types of changes (reboot, reinstall, etc...) - all to no avail.  Same error on startup.

The windows firewalls are being managed by McAfee Endpoint Security.

Looking for some help here please.  Thanks.

Comment: what VM tech and what is the network setup of your guest VM ?

Comment: I am VPNing into their network using Citrix.  Beyond that, I have no visibility into how they are implementing their VMs.

Comment: Seems like very restricted environment... Could well be a firewall. Try setting it up on 8080 or even better 443 or 80

Comment: Tomcat should not be making outgoing connections at all. Can you post a full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the perfect answer or not but you need to change the start time limit of tomcat, timeouts, because if your application is taking too long to start and the tomcat has wait period of 30 seconds then it will force shutdown the tomcat if the application wont start in 30 seconds.

And also before starting the tomcat try to disable the antivirus for couple of minutes, antivirus might be stopping the tomcat to access your network.

Comment: I have altered many "connection" settings including timeout to try and get more information.  This has yielded very little.

Comment: The client is a huge company and locks their machines down very tight.  I have little or no control over McAfee.  I am starting to believe this is the culprit.

Comment: Any antivirus will stop running an application which access your public or private network, try running it as administrator and see if it helps.